# How to delete a paragraph under a heading

Tags: microsoft-word

***Heading 1***
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

***Heading 2***
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

***Heading 1***
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
....

I would like to delete all the contents under all "Heading 1" including the heading itself. How can I do that? I have a lot of Heading 1, so the manual process is really time-consuming.

Comment: Do you always need to delete one paragraph under heading 1? If not, how to decide how many?

Comment: I also confused that does Heading 1 and Heading 2 have the same level?

Comment: Are you asking about deleting everything after some text that says "Heading 1" or about deleting everything after text in the style "Heading 1?" Everything between Heading 1 and Heading 2? Normally, virtually everything in your document will be after a Heading 1 style if you are using the styles the way they are designed.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample document? Here is my article on how to do that. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete all the information under a heading section the easiest way by far is to use the **Navigation Pane**.

You can open the Navigation Pane by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> or going to the **View** tab in the ribbon and enabling it:

[image: Navigation Pane Enable]

Then in the Navigation Pane you can right click headings and select **Delete**. This will delete everything in that heading section and is a very quick way to empty out a document template.

[image]

You can find out more at [Use the Navigation pane in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-navigation-pane-in-word-394787be-bca7-459b-894e-3f8511515e55) which is also where my images were sourced.